# How to replace image (icon) insted of input type file with same action in text area?

Tags: html, css

I am new in web design. I want to build a comment system for my web site, I have some issues with text area. How to replace the image (icon) instead of input type file with the same action in the textarea?

How can I implement the same?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="upload">
    <div class="image-upload">

   <textarea name="" id="txt" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <label for="file-input">
     <img src="">
   </label>

  <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
 </div>
 </div >
```

**CSS**

```
.upload{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
input{
position:absolute;
bottom:10px;
right:2px;
}
textarea{
display:block;
width:500px;
}
.image-upload > input
{
display: none;
}
.image-upload img
{
width: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I tried many times but not working.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly you want do?

Comment: @yogendarji how to put an icon inside textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an icon in the textarea, insert the `<img>` tag for the icon after the `<textarea>`, then add the following to the CSS:

```
.icon-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```